# Azure Portal unable to create new os disk, vm image, etc

Tags: azure, azureportal

Logging into one of my Azure accounts I'm brought directly into the New Preview Portal - and not given a choice of using the old one.

When I click "new", trying to create a new image from a blob that's in my storage container, the only choices of new things I have are listed under "marketplace" and are all pre-packaged choices.

In the original Azure site, I simply  go to "virtual machines, disks, create" - and name it, then navigate to the vhd in the vhd url field, and create the disk.

Then just create the image, then the vm.

I have, or see, NONE of the abilities to do this in the new preview portal.

If anybody is following and has a clue to how to do these things in the new portal, I'd love to hear about or get a link :)

Thanks!
Rob
ps...not sure if this is the place to post this question as everytime I post an Azure question someone says this isn't the place for such questions - maybe tell Microsoft that? I got to this page by clicking the support icon within the Azure Portal - just FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find all disks under `OS disks (classic)` :

[image: OS disks]

Note that if you click the star, it then appears in your resource list without having to browse/search.

At this point, you can select your disk and create a new VM from it:

[image: Create VM]

Comment: Hi David, Thank you! Right on the money...appreciate the help!

Comment: David, I see that, but how do you create a disk? I just have the ability to select existent disks but not to create new one. Not from there, neither from the new button.

Comment: @fernaramburu _[“The new Azure portal does not currently have the ability
to make an uploaded VHD file an OS disk. Instead use PowerShell...”](http://windowsitpro.com/azure/make-uploaded-vhd-os-disk-new-portal)_
You can't be disappointed enough when it comes to Microsoft.
They should at least make clear that this basic functionality is missing
in the new portal, in order to 1. save you the time of searching for it
2. explain why, so everyone can understand.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very easy way to use a "Cloned" VHD of a VM to create a brand new VM

## Create a VM from a specialized VHD disk

[image]

It is very simple just press the button above,
edit your settings, and hit create and that is it!

[image]

Took me around 5 mins total to deploy a "copied" VHD from one VM and use it to create a brand new VM.

You can use

### CloudBerry Explorer for Microsoft Azure Storage

[Explorer for Microsoft Azure Storage](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx)

Real easy to do.

1. Set up CloudBerry to Access your Azure Storage Account.
2. Turn off your Original VM.
3. Use CloudBerry to copy your Original VM.
4. Rename that copied VHD to something else.
5. Transfer that renamed VHD to a storage account where you are going to create a brand new VM
6. Click the Deploy to Azure button on this post.
7. Edit your parameters, The URL to your Renamed Copied VHD, Operating system, and etc.

Then you are done.

5 mins should be it!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use powershell :)

```
$storage = "[storage account name]"
$storagePath = "https://$storage.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/myosdisk.vhd"

$diskName = "MyOSDisk"
$label = "MyOSDisk"
Add-AzureDisk -DiskName $diskName -Label $label -MediaLocation $storagePath -OS Windows
```

Hope that helps,

Damian